# If I have a collection of classes how can I return a collection of a single attribute of all the classes?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine I have 20 People objects.

```
IQueryable<Person> People;
```

How could I return a List of all the Peoples names using a linq query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<String> names = People.Select(p => p.Name);
```

This assumes that a the property is of type String and is called Name.

edit:
If you specifically want a list, you can add a ToList() call on the end:

```
List<String> names = People.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var names = from person in People select person.Name
```